# What has gone wrong in this proof of the Yoneda Lemma

Tags: category-theory, yoneda-lemma

Here is a snippet of the first part of the proof of the Yoneda Lemma. The last line says the square commutes, but I don't get that it commutes. So what has gone wrong in the proof?

Following one direction I get $F(h)\circ F(\alpha) (f)$ while in the direction I get $F(\alpha\circ h)(f)$ where $\alpha:y_2\rightarrow x$

[image]

Comment: Is it because breaking up a contra-variant functor swaps the order of the composition?

Answer (score 3):

The left-hand morphism is slightly misleading; it's not $h$—rather, it's *precomposition* by $h$.

To see why the square commutes, let $g \in \mathrm{Hom}(y_2,x)$ (that is $g : y_2 \to x$).

The composite along the left and top of the square is given by
$$g \mapsto g \circ h \mapsto F(g \circ h)(f)$$
The composite along the bottom and right of the square is given by
$$g \mapsto F(g)(f) \mapsto F(h)(F(g)(f))$$
But $F(h)(F(g)(h)) = (F(h) \circ F(g))(f) = F(g \circ h)(f)$ since $F$ is a contravariant functor.

So the square commutes.